# Numpy rotation matrix multiplication

Tags: python, numpy, matrix, rotational-matrices

I want to calculate and multply a sequence of rotation matrix using numpy. I've written this code to do my job,

```
def npmat(angle_list):
    aa = np.full((nn, n, n),np.eye(n))
    c=0
    for j in range(1,n):
        for i in range(j):
            th = angle_list[c]
            aa[c,i,i]=aa[c,j,j] = np.cos(th)
            aa[c,i,j]= np.sin(th)
            aa[c,j,i]= -np.sin(th)
            c+=1
    return np.linalg.multi_dot(aa)

n,nn=3,3
#nn=n*(n-1)/2
angle_list= array([1.06426904, 0.27106789, 0.56149785])

npmat(angle_list)=
array([[ 0.46742875,  0.6710055 ,  0.57555363],
       [-0.84250501,  0.53532228,  0.06012796],
       [-0.26776049, -0.51301235,  0.81555052]])
```

But I've to apply this function over 10K times and this is very slow and feels like not using numpy to its full potential. Is there a more efficient a do this in numpy?

Comment: Please add an example of input and expected output.

Comment: what is done 10k times ?   n=10k? nn= 10k ? 10k angle_lists? 10k items in angle list? and rotate alpha then rotate beta is rotate alpha+beta?  can you specify more precisely.

Comment: that means 10K angle list i.e say `angle_list=angle[0]` and `angle.shape = (10K,nn)`

Answer (score 1):

EDIT: Since it seems like you are looking for the product of these matrices, you can apply the matrices without constructing them. It might also make sense to just compute the cosine and sine without having vectorized that first.

```
n=3
nn= n*(n-1)//2

theta_list = np.array([1.06426904, 0.27106789, 0.56149785])

sin_list = np.sin(theta_list)
cos_list = np.cos(theta_list)
A = np.eye(n)
c=0
for i in range(1,n):
    for j in range(i):
        ri = np.copy(A[i])
        rj = np.copy(A[j])

        A[i] = cos_list[c]*ri + sin_list[c]*rj
        A[j] = -sin_list[c]*ri + cos_list[c]*rj
        c+=1

print(A.T) // transpose at end because its faster to update A[i] than A[:,i]
```

If you want to compute each of the matrices explicitly here is a vectorized version of some of your original code.

```
n=4
nn= n*(n-1)//2

theta_list = np.random.rand(nn)*2*np.pi

sin_list = np.sin(theta_list)
cos_list = np.cos(theta_list)

aa = np.full((nn, n, n),np.eye(n))
ii,jj = np.tril_indices(n,k=-1)
cc = np.arange(nn)

aa[cc,ii,ii] = cos_list[cc]
aa[cc,jj,jj] = cos_list[cc]
aa[cc,ii,jj] = -sin_list[cc]
aa[cc,jj,ii] = sin_list[cc]
```

Comment: Well, sorry for the mistake, thats actually `n`. I actually copied that part from my larger piece of code and simplified a bit to show the probelm.

Comment: Also I don't see any performance gain using this method. This and earlier both runs at about 50-60 us in my machine

Comment: I'm not sure that this will actually be faster than yours, but have you tried with larger `n`? For small `n` I wouldn't expect to see much difference. Also, have you tried with the sparse matrices?

Answer (score 1):

A solutions with more  vectorisation levels :

```
def npmats(angle):
    a,b = angle.shape
    aa = np.full((a,b, n,n),np.eye(n))
    for j in range(1,n):
        for i in range(j):
            aa[:,:,i,i]=aa[:,:,j,j] = np.cos(angle)
            sinangle=np.sin(angle)
            aa[:,:,i,j]= sinangle
            aa[:,:,j,i]= -sinangle
    bb=np.empty((a,n,n))
    for i in range(a):
        bb[i]=np.linalg.multi_dot(aa[i])
    return bb
```

It seems reasonably fast:

```
In [9]: angle= np.random.rand(10000,nn)

In [10]: %time res = npmats(angle)
Wall time: 205 ms
```

Comment: I don't know what machine you are using but on my machine, for my current working data, `In [9]: angle.shape
Out[9]: (8640, 15)

In [10]: timeit np.stack(npmat(i) for i in angle)
1 loop, best of 3: 3.87 s per loop

In [11]: timeit npmats(angle)
1 loop, best of 3: 3.48 s per loop
`